# What is a fakechain?

Tags: blockchain, monerod-commands, blockchain-import

The output of `monerod --help` and `monero-blockchain-import --help` show a `--keep-fakechain` option:

```
  --keep-fakechain                      Don't delete any existing database when
                                        in fakechain mode.
```

What is a "fakechain"? What is "fakechain mode"? How do I create a "fakechain" and enter the "fakechain mode"?

(Monero version: Oxygen Orion v0.17.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

> What is a "fakechain"?

A chain that's not on mainnet or testnet.

> How do I create a "fakechain" and enter the "fakechain mode"?

Run with the flag `--regtest` and generate/mine some blocks.